# How can I copy a large file (11GB) file to a thumb drive

Tags: windows, fat32

Can you please tell me how I can copy a large file (11GB) to a thumb drive (16GB)?

I am copying from Ubuntu and I get a message saying that the file is too large when it reaches 4GB.

I want a Windows machine to be able to read that file on the thumb drive after the copy.

Comment: The android tag is a bit confusing here, since the question doesn't really mention anything about phones

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Format the thumb drive using NTFS. FAT32 limits you to 4GB.

If you need assistance with formating, follow the instructions in this link:
http://www.ntfs.com/quest22.htm

Comment: The OP wants a "windows machine to be able to read that file on the thumb drive after the copy."

Comment: @Zoredache: To answer your question, there's no native support for android to support NTFS format from SD card. Since OP said thumb drive, I'm assuming USB type.

Comment: And NTFS happens to be the default Windows filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative is to split it with a file splitter into <4 GB chunks. For example, you can use [File Splitter](http://www.filesplitter.org/). You will have to rejoin the files later though.

Comment: why 'File Splitter' for windows when there is `split` on ubuntu?

Comment: @akira, Because of the file needs to be used on Windows.

Comment: first you have to split it on ubuntu in order to BRING it onto the stick. and you can easily merge the splitted files on windows via 'copy' (see http://elliottback.com/wp/combine-split-files-in-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Ubuntu supports it and you're Windows target is Vista or Windows 7, [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) may be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Using a windows machine you can convert directly to NTFS without reformatting if you wish. Run this on the command line:

convert x: /fs:ntfs